# Keras: Retrieving accuracy for each model output

Tags: python, performance, deep-learning, keras

I am currently implementing a Keras model with multiple inputs and outputs. The number of inputs and outputs are identical.

The output part of my code looks as follows. It contains for-loop as it is supposed to be a dynamic, multi-stream model:

```
...
for s in range(NUM_STREAMS):
        x[s] = Dense3(x[s])
        logits.append(Softmax0(x[s]))

model = Model(
    inputs=[inp_ele for inp_ele in inp],
    outputs=[logit for logit in logits]
)
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now I want to retrieve the accuracy for each `logit` within the model. However, applying `print(model.metrics_names)` gives me the following (it is a 3 stream model in this example):

```
['loss', 'activation_8_loss', 'activation_8_loss', 'activation_8_loss', 
'activation_8_acc', 'activation_8_acc', 'activation_8_acc']
```

Now when I try to retrieve the history object from the `model.fit` function, it gives me a

```
KeyError: [-1] #Instead of the -1, it is respectively and of the lower list-indecies
```

I tried retrieving the accuracy using the following methods, and none of them works.

```
print(history.history['activation_8_acc'])
print(history.history['activation_8_acc'][-1])
print(history.history[-1])
```

How can I retrieve the individual accuracies? Or if it is possible, how can I retrieve the mean accuracy for this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a line `print(history.history)` which outputted:

```
'activation_8_loss_3': [1.3723259580135345], 'loss': [4.1188646435737608], 'activation_8_loss_1': [1.3680831426382065], 'activation_8_loss_2': [1.37177708029747], 'activation_8_acc_1': [0.46729998335242273] ...
```

which revealed that `print(model.metrics_names)` was not telling the whole story.